# ActiveRecord fails to update HABTM relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm using a simple model for user authorisation with two ActiveRecords `User` and `Role`
`User` and `Role` have a HABTM relation to each other.

I tried to created a user interface for assigning roles to users with simple checkboxes - just like in [Railscasts Episode #17](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes).

My problem is that neither `User#new` nor `User#update_attributes` use the parameters submitted by my form to update the relation between the `User` object and its roles. `params[:user][:role_ids]` contains the correct values. But calling `@user.roles` right after `User.new(params[:user])` or `@user.update_attributes(params[:user])` returns an empty array.

Manually assigning roles with `@user.roles` or `@user.role_ids` works, but not the *"magic"* inside `User#new` or `User#update_attributes`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your controller and view code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The chances are high that you have either attr_accessible or attr_protected call in your User model, thus making role_ids protected from mass assignment.

If you really want to update roles via mass assignment operators, just add

```
attr_accessible :role_ids
```

to your model. However, I recommend you reading http://railspikes.com/2008/9/22/is-your-rails-application-safe-from-mass-assignment first, just to know all potential problems of mass assignment.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just read about that yesterday, but missed it when creating my models.