# Alternative to mass assignment for HABTM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many, mass-assignment

I have a similar situation to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755774/activerecord-fails-to-update-habtm-relation), which was already posted. Koraktor has asked

> I'm using a simple model for user authorisation with two ActiveRecords User and Role User and Role have a HABTM relation to each other.
>   .
>   .
>   Manually assigning roles with @user.roles or @user.role_ids works, but not the "magic" inside User#new or User#update_attributes.

Oleg suggested that

```
attr_accessible :role_ids
```

be added to the user model.  This would allow mass assignment operators to update roles. However, he cautioned against using this approach because of security concerns.

I have a follow up question to Oleg's response -

In this situation, is there a recommended method to update roles without using mass-assignment?

Also, assuming

1. you authenticate users,
2. only allow administrators to CRUD users by putting a before_filter in the users_controller,

is mass-assignment of role_ids still a valid concern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mass assignment is a feature of Rails provided for using less code for updating a model like this

```
Model.create(params[:model])
@model.update_parameters(params[:model])
```

instead of

```
@model.field1 = params[:model][:field1]
@model.field2 = params[:model][:field2]
...
@model.save
```

But with this feature, comes the risk of updating values which we dont intend. For example, if we want just field1, field2 and field3 to be updated by the user and you use `update_parameters` for mass assignment, there is a risk of updating field4, if one is passing `model[user][field4]=some_value` either from url or by any other ways. If we are explicitly assigning the fields in the code, we do not have this risk. But then we will have to set the values for each field(wherever we are updating or creating) which is not very productive.

So, for using the mass assignment feature, we have 2 options. First is `attr_protected`

```
attr_protected :field4
```

This will protect field4 from being saved from mass assignment from params[:model] even if it contains field4. For saving field4, we have to call the setter for field4 explicitly in 
the code(`@model.field4 =`). But, the problem with `attr_protected` is that Rails may provide some other attributes that we may not know for mass assignment. For example, if we define

```
has_many :model2s
```

in Model.rb, Rails will provide a method `model2_ids=` automatically and this can be accessed by mass assignment.(If we give `model[model2_ids]=` in the url, it will create associations, not intended at all). So, there is a chance of missing attributes like this while using `attr_protected`.

So, the recommended method is to use `attr_accessible`

```
attr_accessible :field1, :field2, :field3
```

This will make these fields open for mass assignment and all other attributes in the model not available for mass assignment. So, the recommended way is to make those attributes which we are providing in a form for users to edit as `attr_accessible` and all other parameters will be protected. But, while using this you have to make sure you have included all the attributes you need for edit as `attr_accessible`.

In your case, since you want the user to edit the `role_ids` and you are providing access to CRUD for admin users only, I think you can use `attr_accessible :role_ids`. The alternative would be to assign `role_ids` explictely like `.role_ids = params[:user][:role_ids]`. You should use this, if you have another form where you dont want the user to edit the role_ids.

Comment: Thank you for this very complete explanation.  One more question - if I assign role_ids explicitly, I'll still need to use 'attr_accessible role_ids', right?

Comment: No..`attr_accessible` has nothing to do with explicit assignment..even if you declare `attr_accessible :field1` or `attr_proteected :role_ids`, you will be able to explicitely assign `@user.roles =` or `@user.role_ids = `. In the question you mentioned, he forgot to add `role_ids` to the `attr_accessible` list. But, he was still able to assign `@user.roles = ` or `@user.role_ids = `. `attr_accessible` and `attr_protected` affects mass assignment only.